# Always repeating random pick

Tags: c++, random

I have a code here. The objective is to create a multiple choice quiz where questions are coming from a text file and will be picked randomly to be displayed. I was able to do a multiple choice, the problem is when it generates, the question that was already pick and displayed are being displayed again. Also the choices are coming from the answers on the text file, but the problem is the choices are being displayed repeatedly in a question.

So I want to know how to not display the pick question again, and how the choices are not being displayed repeatedly.

Example output

```
1. what month do we celebrate Christmas?
a.december
b.december
c.january
d.december



//Randomizes the questionList vector
random_shuffle(questionList.begin(), questionList.end());
//Goes through every Test question

for(int i = 0; i < questionList.size(); i++){
    vector <Test> randomAnswer;     
    //Puts the correct Answer into it first
    randomAnswer.push_back(questionList[i]);
    //Then randomly gets 3 other answers from questionList
    while(randomAnswer.size() < 4)
    {
    int random = rand();
    if(random != i){
        randomAnswer.push_back(questionList[rand() % (questionList.size() - 1)]);
    }            
    //Shuffle the answers
    random_shuffle(randomAnswer.begin(), randomAnswer.end());
    //Print the question
    cout << questionList[i].getQuestion() << ":" << endl;
    //Initialize the first choice character to 'A'
    char ch = 'A';
    //Prints the shuffled answers
    for(int j = 0; j < randomAnswer.size(); j++)
    {
        cout << ch << ") " << randomAnswer[j].getAnswer() << endl;
        //Increment 'A' so it can print 'B' and so forth
        ++ch;
    }
    //Get users response
    cout << "\nYour answer: ";
    cin  >> response;
    //Bool data type to determine if the correct answer was found
    bool isCorrect = false;
    switch(toupper(response)) 
    {
    case 'A':
        if(randomAnswer[0].getAnswer()==questionList[i].getAnswer())
        isCorrect = true;
        break;
    case 'B':
        if(randomAnswer[1].getAnswer()==questionList[i].getAnswer())
        isCorrect = true;
        break;
    case 'C':
        if(randomAnswer[2].getAnswer()==questionList[i].getAnswer())
        isCorrect = true;
        break;
    case 'D':
        if(randomAnswer[3].getAnswer()==questionList[i].getAnswer())
        isCorrect = true;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "\nIncorrect input.\n";
    }
    //If the answer was found print "Correct" else "Wrong"
    if(isCorrect)
    {
        cout << "\nYou got the answer correct!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nYou got the answer WRONG!\n"
        << "Correct answer was " << questionList[i].getAnswer() << 
        endl;
```

Comment: That overload of `std::random_shuffle` will soon be deprecated. Better to use `std::shuffle`.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is incorrect, you insert the correct answer in the list and then randomly pick three answers. Visual example (1 is correct):

```
1 2 3 4
Insert 1 into randomAnswer
Randomly pick three numbers and insert them into randomAnswer: ex (2, 1, 3)
```

The correct approach is to take all four answers and shuffle them. Psuedocode

```
swap(questionList[i], *(questionList.end() - 1));
Insert questionList[i]
Shuffle questionList.begin() - questionList.end() - 2 and randomly pick 3
```

Comment: Can I ask another question?